# How to decrease execution time of maximum sum of k consecutive numbers in a list algorithm in python

Tags: python, algorithm

my problem is to find the maximum sum of k consecutive numbers in a given list.
for instance: 
l = [2,3,5,1,6] then for k =2 the result would be 8(3+5).
I know a good algorithm would be to first find the sum of the first k numbers then add the next element to the sum and subtract the first element of the k numbers:

```
2+3 => 5
5-2+5 => 8
...
```

I came up with this:

```
def f(l, k):
    M= 0
    temp = sum(l[0:k])
    for i in range(1,k):
        temp += a[l+1]-l[i-1]
        if temp > M:
            M = temp
    return M
```

but unfortunately it only works with k = 2?
so I have two issues:

1. Why my code doesn't work with higher k's?(what is the bug and how can I fix it?)
2. Is there any better way(time wise) to solve the main problem?will this algorithm work quick enough if for example len(l) = 100000 and k = 2000?how can I determine its execution time only by looking at the code?

Comment: Define "quick enough".

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I meant quickest possible actually

Comment: Your description is correct and the fastest, but implementation is fully wrong - it is not real code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea you described is correct, but your implementation is wrong.

1. Your variable `M` is equivalent to `cumax` below. It should be
   initialized to the sum of the first k items, not 0.
2. Your range of the start of the `k` numbers to consider should be `N - k + 1`, the largest position in the sequence for a window of size k.
3. Your `temp` is equivalent to `cusum`. The line `temp += a[l+1]-l[i-1]` is wrong. I don't know where you get `a` from. I
   think you meant `temp += l[i + k] - l[i - 1]`.

   ```
   def f(l, k):
       assert len(l) >= k

       # Start of max sum of k consecutive number
       start_idx = 0
       # Current max sum of k consecutive number
       cumax = cusum = sum(l[:k])

       # Slide a window of size k from second element onwards
       N = len(l)
       for i in range(1, N - k + 1):
           # Subtract element before start of window and add rightmost element
           cusum = cusum + l[i + k - 1] - l[i - 1]

           # Update start of and latest max sum of k consecutive number if
           # necessary
           if cusum > cumax:
               cumax = cusum
               start_idx = i

       return start_idx, cumax
   ```

The time complexity is O(N) and memory complexity is O(1). In reality, for long sequences, the approach by @dobkind using convolution would probably be fastest.

```
def f_convolve(l, k):
    start_idx = np.argmax(np.convolve(l, np.ones(k,), 'valid'))
    return start_idx, np.sum(l[start_idx : start_idx + k])
```

If you have memory to spare and `l` is not too large, this implementation works even better than the previous two

```
def f_numpy_cusum(l, k):
    cumsums = np.cumsum(l)
    cumsums[k :] -= cumsums[: len(cumsums) - k ]
    cumsums = cumsums[ k- 1:]
    start = np.argmax(cumsums)
    return start, np.sum(l[start : start + k])
```

The time runs for the above 3 functions with `len(l)` = 100000 and `k` = 2000 are

`f`
32.6 ms +- 78.5 us per loop (mean +- std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

`f_convolve`
26.3 ms +- 183 us per loop (mean +- std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

`f_numpy_cusum`
718 us +- 3.81 us per loop (mean +- std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

Answer (score 2):

We should use dynamic programming for this purpose and do this in `O(n)` complexity

```
from random import randint

test=[randint(1,10) for i in range(5)]
# find cumulative sum use np.cumsum or write is yourself
print(test)
cumsum=[0]*(len(test)+1)
cumsum[1]=test[0]
for i in range(2,len(test)+1):
    cumsum[i]=cumsum[i-1]+test[i-1]
print(cumsum)
#define k
k=3
# m denotes the maximum element
m=0
for i in range(len(test)-k+1):
   m=max(m,cumsum[k+i]-cumsum[i])
   print(cumsum[k+i]-cumsum[i])
# the answer is printed 
print(m)
```

INPUT

```
[10, 5, 1, 1, 7]
k=3
```

OUTPUT

```
16
```

Comment: but the output should be 16 for that input

Comment: @AntiMatterDynamite I understand i made a small bug in my code i corrected it thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use `numpy.convolve` as follows:

```
k = 2     
max_sum = np.max(np.convolve([2,3,5,1,6], np.ones(k,), 'same'))
```

With `k=2000` and `len(l)=100000` this code is running in 0.04 sec on my i7 machine:

```
from random import randint
import time

def test_max_sum(k, len_l):
    num_trials = 100
    total = 0
    test = [randint(1, 10) for i in range(len_l)]
    for i in range(num_trials):
        start = time.clock()
        max_sum = np.max(np.convolve(test, np.ones(k, ), 'same'))
        end = time.clock()
        total += end - start
    total /= num_trials
    print total
```

Comment: The mode should be `valid`, not `same`.

Answer (score 1):

This is really not my expertise, but wouldnt zipping together the lists be quite effective?

Something in the lines of:

```
from itertools import islice

l = [2,3,5,1,6]

def max_consecutive(ar, k=2):
    combos = zip(*(islice(ar,i,None) for i in range(k)))
    return max(map(sum, combos))

print(max_consecutive(l)) 
print(max_consecutive(l, k=3))
```

Returns `8` and `12`